# Efficient write only (CREATE/UPDATE) object persistence in EF6 - stored procedures?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

It seems a lot has changed in EF (code first) since many of the questions on SO were written... many refer to EF4 and I am using EF6, I know stored procedures are a new feature in EF6 for instance.

My application periodically calls an Xml web service and simply dumps the objects in a database; I have a C# object for each Xml type which maps directly to one DB table using EF.

Objects may be created or updated depending if they are already in the DB. My application has no interest in the content of the objects and should *not* keep them in memory as it may be running for weeks at a time.

What is an efficient way to Create-or-Update objects in this scenario? I am imagining that my `DbContext` will be created (and disposed) each time the web service is polled, so it will *never* already know what objects are in the DB. In a non-EF world I'd probably create a stored-procedure `CreateOrUpdate(...)` so I wonder if there is a simple parallel.

I do not *need* to use stored procedures with EF but it sounds like it might be a nicer idea. And since we're not used to EF and not all our modules are using it, haveing the stored-procedures in the DB in case someone else wants to use them seems useful.

Comment: Yes, it all makes sens, whats your question ? A stored procedure is always nice to have and you can use it in EF6

Comment: Or just create a function that uses Entity/Linq to do the job

Comment: Take look at Dapper - it's a much lighter layer. https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: I'm asking how to do this - and what is efficient to avoid loading objects I don't need, etc. If I use EF stored procs does it generate them behind the scenes and I use it as normal?